# Would this Omron G5V-1 DC3 be suitable, even at my battery's 4v2 fully charged voltage?

Tags: voltage, switches, relay, amperage

I'm in a state of deep confusion and would appreciate some guidance. Please no sarcastic answers, I genuinely don't know! I've included links to the components in question at the end.

So I'm designing a simple circuit that includes a switch and a relay coil, both powered by a Lithium-ion battery. The nominal voltage of the battery is 3v6, though its voltage range is 4v2 to 2v5. The relay is rated for 3v and it's data sheet says the coil offers 60Ω of resistance, meaning when the battery is at its fully charged voltage of 4v2, the coil will be pulling 70mA of current - 40% more than the 50mA it is rated for!

However, the data sheet also gives its 'max' voltage as 200% of the rated 3v at 23℃, which theoretically makes the max amperage 100mA, though it doesn't say for how long it could sustain such a current.

There is a 5v variant of the same relay, however its 'must operate' voltage is 70% of the rated 5v, so my 4v2 battery wouldn't need to drop much voltage before it failed to operate the relay. The battery's voltage range seems to prevent it matching nicely with many comparable relays.

1. [The battery](https://battery101.co.uk/products/samsung-50e-21700-5000mah-button-top-with-protection): Samsung 50E 21700 5000mAh
2. [The switch](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/204154057901?hash=item2f8887b4ad:g:eDAAAOSwDFBjc9p7&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA4L1iVoIjw5KBG5Woz12TVHHLmcfhbBZhERDWHivPg3bsO8ecZF9iOB0L8ZAmSX9Ds2tARjnRMZm5Ujou2loSmPYXQPS4zZyupaBDQAPOy8ZqpnpgsWFV3Ra9aUDQ3V7a9dJd8YO8IHcIuW60d4leKLL9p35s5DcN8jrFnGgurP%2B6Hn9iIMwfLYk3L9Cdw04%2F7sXDLrX5oSqg0wR0zcQWwJuufGKNKNjDErzPaU1AyBSM1VpGTvLmSJ4YPAf34COKgmsQ0P2Yrr1A0fFcQiB6VEsZkzm%2F8K%2B0KX8mwPDpbOjO%7Ctkp%3ABFBM6PfYlPRi): it's an eBay special (very suspect I know)
3. [The relay](https://uk.farnell.com/omron/g5v-1-3dc/relay-spdt-125vac-30vdc-0-5a/dp/2065727?st=3v%20dc%20relay): Omron Electronic Components G5V-1 DC3

[image: A small diagram of the circuit]

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a non-latching electromechanical relay in something battery-powered? Usually you want to avoid that kind of load in a battery-powered device.

Comment: @Hearth to put it bluntly no! I'd actually not considered I could use a latching relay. Transistors or optoisolators have also been suggested to me, and now your comment has made me think maybe I should look into those too.

Comment: Yes, I would typically use a MOSFET for this, unless you need isolation, in which case use an SSR or a latching relay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contact resistance of S1 is 100 milliohms, not 100 ohms.

I don't see anything in the relay datasheet about operation at 200% of the coil voltage as pulsed or some other form of non-continuous.  Based on that, operation at 140% should be ok.

Comment: Thanks. FWIW, it's not going to be used anywhere that fire would be an issue. It's more reliability I'm concerned with. Also I've updated the diagram to show the correct resistance for the switch - well spotted!